# Flask does not list outputs of multiple files

Tags: flask, werkzeug, flask-uploads

I am using Flask to render some analysis based on taking image as an input using Flask reuploaded and werkzeug. Though the input accepts multiple images, the output is rendered of only one image instead of all the images that were uploaded.
There is no error message that I am receiving.

**HTML code:**

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"><p>
                <input type="file" name="file" multiple
                       accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload">
```

**Post request**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # checks whether or not the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files['file']

        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No file selected for uploading')
            return redirect(request.url)
        files = request.files.getlist('files[]')

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd() +
                                   UPLOAD_INPUT_IMAGES_FOLDER, file.filename))

            flash('File successfully uploaded')

            # calls the ocr_processing function to perform text extraction
            extracted_text = ocr_processing(file)
            print(extracted_text)
            match = extracted_text.lower()
            df = pd.read_csv("/Users/ri/Desktop/DPL/DPL.csv")

            for row in df.Pattern_String:
                result = ratio(row, match)
                print(result)
                if result >= 10:

                else:
                    return render_template('uploads/results.html',
                                           msg='Processed successfully!',
                                           match=match,
                                           img_src=UPLOAD_INPUT_IMAGES_FOLDER + file.filename)


    else:
        flash('Allowed file types are txt, pdf, png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
        return redirect(request.url)
```

Comment: Unrelated. Flask-Uploads is not well maintained, you should consider using Flask-Reuploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `files = request.files.getlist('files[]')`, but then you do not use it.

You need to iterate over all uploaded files, ie you need e.g. a for loop.

I would start renaming the misleading input name `file` to `files` and then start over.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I add a "for" loop with [for files in file] (followed by an if loop) it will expect a return statement. This will break the "for" loop which is already nested within the "if" loop. How can I make changes such that the code does not break?

Comment: No for loop expects a return statement. And certainly the for loop will be terminated when you exit the function with return. You need to collect the results in the for loop, and the return the complete result.